# Errors while saving pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using python 3.6.I have python dictionary,name dict. I want to save it in my system for future reference.So I used following code.

```
import pickle as cpick
OutputDirectory='C:/pickle/'
with open("".join([OutputDirectory, "dict.pkl"]), mode='wb') as fp:
        cpick.dump(dict, fp, cpick.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

But I'm getting following error after running the code,

```
  with open("".join([OutputDirectory, "dict.pkl"]), mode='wb') as fp:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'C:/pickle/dict.pkl'
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does `C:/pickle/` directory actually exist?

Comment: Have you tried by `//` in path?

Comment: yes @roganjosh,it exist.

Comment: @chandra are you saying to try C://pickle//?

Comment: try `C:\\pickle\\ `

Comment: Yes,it's running now @suit.Thank you